# Data validation - Drop down list with no duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, vba

Could you please assist me  with **removing duplicates** in a **drop down list**. The list is not static. Example:

**Before**

```
James
Peter
James
Nick
Peter
```

**After**

```
James
Peter
Nick
```

I am not sure what formula to use data validation formula box.

I had attempted the below, but no success:

```
=OFFSET($C$13,0,0,COUNTIF(C:C,"?*")-1)
```

Comment: Have you already tried something like [this](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=97:remove-duplicates-or-create-a-list-of-unique-records-using-excel-formula&catid=77&Itemid=473) to remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 - With the original names in column A, put this array formula¹ somewhere off to the right in the second row. I'll use Z2.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A:A )), MATCH(0, COUNTIF(Z$1:Z1, A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A:A ))&""), 0)), "")
```

Fill down until you run out of names and then a few more rows to allow for future expansion.

Step 2 - Go to Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager and create a new name.

```
Name: listNames
Scope: Workbook
Refers to: =Sheet2!$Z$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$Z:$Z, MATCH("zzz", IF(LEN(Sheet2!X:X), Sheet2!$Z1:$Z98) ))
```

Step 3 - Go to the cell you want you data validation and use Data ► Data Tools ► Data Validation.

```
Allow: List
Source: listNames
```

[image: named_range_data_validation]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Works amazingly well. I will just hidden the column from the user on the far side. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a different answer, and this does work, but wasn't what I was looking for.  The class I took had me format as table and use =unique(A2:A6) in column B.  Then I used that list as the target for the validation list, and hid the column.

I was hoping to find out I could just enter the =unique("desired range") in the Source box.
[Screen shot of Excel Data Validation box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axxJr.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).